Who gave God the name 'Jealous' as referred to in Exodus 34:14?
We read in Exodus 34:14 ( KJV):

For thou shalt worship no other god: for the Lord, whose name is Jealous, is a jealous God.

Israel addressed God by different names including 'Yahweh'. But one seldom reads of God having been addressed by the name Jealous. Is it something God gave to himself to drive Israel home to the fact that any breach of the First Commandment would never be tolerated ? What is the view of Bible scholars on the topic ?

It is very rare that anyone but YHWH/Jehovah/God gives Him a name other than Himself - almost all the names and titles of God in the OT were announced by God Himself.  Here is a sample:
El Shaddai

Gen 17:1 - And when Abram was ninety years old and nine, the LORD appeared to Abram, and said unto him, I am God-Almighty; walk before me, and be perfect.
See also Gen 28:3; Gen 35:11; Gen 43:14; Gen 48:3

El Elyon

Gen 14:18 KJV - And Melchizedek king of Salem brought forth bread and wine: and he was the priest of God Most High.
see also Gen 14:19; Gen 14:20; Gen 14:22; Psa 57:2; Psa 78:35

YHWH/Yahweh

Ex 3:15 - God also told Moses, “Say to the Israelites, ‘The LORD, the God of your fathers—the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob—has sent me to you.’ This is My name forever, and this is how I am to be remembered in every generation.

Jehovah Nissi

Ex 17:15 - And Moses built an altar and named it "Jehovahnissi" [= The LORD Is My Banner].

Jehovah Rapha

Ex 15:26 - “If you will diligently listen to the voice of the LORD your God, and do that which is right in his eyes, and give ear to his commandments and keep all his statutes, I will put none of the diseases on you that I put on the Egyptians, for I am the LORD, your healer.”

Jehovah Shammah

Eze 48:35 - The perimeter of the city will be 18,000 cubits, and from that day on the name of the city will be: THE LORD IS THERE.”

Jehovah Tsidkenu

Jer 23:6 - In His days Judah will be saved, and Israel will dwell securely. And this is His name by which He will be called: The LORD Our Righteousness.
See also Jer 33:16

Jehovah Mekoddishkem

Ex 31:13 - “Tell the Israelites, ‘Surely you must keep My Sabbaths, for this will be a sign between Me and you for the generations to come, so that you may know that I am the LORD who sanctifies you.
See also Lev 20:8

El Olamin

Gen 21:33 - And Abraham planted a tamarisk tree in Beersheba, and there he called upon the name of the LORD, the Eternal God.
See also Jer 10:10; Isa 26:4

Qanna

Ex 20:5 - You shall not bow down to them or worship them; for I, the LORD your God, am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of the fathers on their children to the third and fourth generations of those who hate Me,
See also Ex 34:14, Deu 4:24, Deu 5:9, Deu 6:15

[This is far from an exhaustive list!]  Thus, it is quite consistent with the rest of OT usage that God gave these names and titles to Himself as in Ex 34:14 - The "Jealous God".
The point of all these names is simple - each reveals something of the character and nature of God.  In the case of Qanna, the name/title reveals that God will not tolerate any competition - a teaching consistent with the first commandment as the OP suggests.

Moses.
Or allegedly-Moses, or Pseudomoses. Because I don't believe genetic analysis of authorship is ever productive. The work comes to us as a whole - and here it's describing God calling himself jealous. There aren't any earlier usages in the Old Testament or any usages at all outside of it, such as on statues or votive offerings. So if we're supposed to know that it's a particular epithet with a tradition around it - then all that can be said is we no longer know. On a literary approach it therefore has to be taken as a new idea that was only introduced a few chapters ago in Exodus 20:5 and is now being applied as a name.
Which gets to the real problem: we can't very well tell what קַנָּא=qanna meant. It's only used of God, and it's only used in 2 places in Exodus plus another 3 in Deuteronomy (one of which was quoting or using the same formula as Exodus).

Exodus 20:5 - - you shall not serve them for I am a [BLANK] God
Exodus 34:14 (x2) - - you shall worship no other god for I am a [BLANK] God
Deuteronomy 4:24 - - God is a fire-consuming [BLANK] God
Deuteronomy 5:9 - - you shall not serve them for I am a [BLANK] God
Deuteronomy 6:15 - - [you shall not go after other Gods] for God is a [BLANK] God

It's probably not "easy-going" or "of negotiable affections."
LXX rendered all 5 usages as ζηλωτής which is a 'zealous' admirer or follower (Liddell & Scott 1897) who emulates or imitates the one followed. And that fits the sense in Exodus and Deuteronomy poorly enough that the lexicon had to make the LXX's usages into a separate sense of the word.
Which then becomes the etymological root for our word jealous. Which we then read back into the original: the miraculous ability of language to create meaning ex-nihilo.
We don't really know at all. The translations might have been doing us a disservice all along - by pretending it was translatable.
Following after Wittgenstein, there's an argument against deriving the meaning of קַנָּא from its context in Exodus 20:5=Deuteronomy 5:9, because if it only referred to exclusivity of worship then it wouldn't be contributing any meaning to the sentence. For it to have meant anything, it must have been referring to something else.
There's a hazard that the Hebrew conjunction כִּי=for has ended up being translated as 'for' in all of these usages, to smooth over the problem and make the first part of the verse read as an explanation of the lost word in the second part. When it might have been been more like a 'moreover' or a 'seeing as'. That would be a very insidious translation failure, if it deliberately papers over what's been lost.
But the LXX's ζηλωτής might suffer a softer version of this problem. If their usage was about following someone so obsessively that we imitate them, and was able to be used in a general way for intense or exclusive fixations (without its original/etymological sense implying that God imitates mortals) another word like intense or exclusive might by now be a better gloss than jealous if it brings in fewer of the modern ideas we've attached to "jealous".
I think the simplest my dialect can offer would be for God to say "I am a fire-consuming and rar! God" with the little onomatopoeic exclamation 'rar!' able to stand for a wide range of possible intense emotions. Or for scholarly editions it might be better to leave the Hebrew word in situ.
Maybe nobody gave God the name Jealous.

Exodus 34:14:

כִּי לֹא תִשְׁתַּחֲוֶה לְאֵל אַחֵר כִּי יְהֹוָה קַנָּא שְׁמוֹ אֵל קַנָּא הוּא

First you asked

Is it something God gave to himself

Scholars like Richard Elliott Friedman identify Exodus 34:1-28 as being authored by J in Who Wrote the Bible?, and so does Gerhard von Rad.

What is the view of Bible scholars on the topic

Some scholars theorize that 'el qanna' was a formal title of the early Canaanite deity 'El' which was appropriated by the J author, see The relationship of Yahweh and El: a study of two cults and their related mythology. Others believe the epithet 'el qanna' was in early use as a liturgical title similarly to 'el rachum' (merciful god), see Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament:

Late in Israel’s history, for example in the sectarian literature of Qumran, there is a revival of the formation of epithets after the ancient pattern of El plus a sub­stantive, adjective or verbal adjective. In the archaic liturgical material preserved by the epic source in Ex. 34:6, the God of Israel recites his names yhvh yhvh 'el rachum vechanrtun, etc. Are we to read “El the compassionate and merciful” or “the merciful and compas­ sionate god”? It must be said that the epithets here are reminiscent of El’s, ex­pressing the same benign attributes, and I am inclined to think that at least this portion of the long liturgical name is pre-Yahwistic. In any case, this archaic epithet is found in later tradition in slightly variant forms: Dt. 4:31; Jonah 4:2; Ps. 86:15 (probably 'el nose', “a forgiving God,” in Ps. 99:8 is a reminiscence of the long formula with n i’ *wn). A formula somewhat similar is 'el qanna', “a jealous God,” found in Yahwistic tradition (Ex. 34:14), Elohistic tradition (20:5; Josh. 24:19) as well as later tradition (Dt.4:24; 5:9; 6:15; Nah. 1:2). There appear to be no parallels in Canaanite polytheism to the exclusive loyalty demanded by Yahweh in his covenant forms. We judge this epithet to have arisen in the very early cultus of Israel, patterned upon living liturgical epithets of the day.

